# Anonymous function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get better with JavaScript and learn how to utilize my code in functions and keep everything clean. I'm trying to run a function on page-load...

```
var setColors = function(){
        this.init = function(){
            $.getJSON('js/colors.json', function(colors) {
                    $.each(colors, function(i, colors) {
                        $('<li>', {
                            text: colors['color'],
                            'name' : colors['color'],
                            'data-hex' : colors['hex'],
                            'data-var' : colors['var']
                        }).appendTo('#picker');
                    })
            });
        }
    }
```

*(This is not a color-picker, just a list of colors)*
I want `setColors()` to be executed as soon as the page starts. I read that an anonymous function runs automatically, but this one isn't, I also tried...

```
$(function(){
    setColors();
});
```

Below the `setColors()` function and that isn't working ether (The page is just blank). What am I doing wrong and how do I get my function to run on page load? I'm trying to learn so an explanation would be great.

Comment: try $(function(){
    setColors().init();
});

Comment: @jbl without a call to `new` that `init` method will end up on the global object - bad idea.

Comment: @Alnitak oops, thx ! I still have so much to learn

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous functions are not run immediately, you're thinking of *Immediately Invoked Function Expressions* which happen to often use an anonymous function.

To fix your code:

**a)** get rid of the `this.init` function wrapper within the "object" - you're not using it and `this.foo` only makes sense if you're using `new` to instantiate an object:

```
function setColors() {
    return $.getJSON(...);
}
```

Note that returning the `$.getJSON()` result allows you to register additional deferred object handlers, register error handlers, etc.

**b)** call the above function in a `document.ready` handler (which you must do, since the AJAX callback modifies the DOM).

```
$(setColors);
```

NB: the latter *is* a legal way of calling this handler - jQuery will automatically register any function that you pass this way as a `document.ready` handler.  It's similar to writing:

```
$(function() { setColors() })
```

but without the extra (useless) function wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

To have that run once the DOM is initialized, you can put it in a ready listener (jQuery):

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    setColors();
});
```

If you want the function to run automatically as soon as it is encountered in the js, after the } that ends the function, add ();

Something like:

```
function setColors() {
    // Code
}();
```

Comment: the function modifies the DOM - it needs to wait until the DOM has loaded, not be automatically invoked.

Answer (score 0):

setColors doesn't return the next function, or call it at the end. YOu could change it to look like:

```
var setColors = function(){
        this.init = function(){
            $.getJSON('js/colors.json', function(colors) {
                    $.each(colors, function(i, colors) {
                        $('<li>', {
                            text: colors['color'],
                            'name' : colors['color'],
                            'data-hex' : colors['hex'],
                            'data-var' : colors['var']
                        }).appendTo('#picker');
                    })
            });
        }

        init(); // <--- change
    }
```

Which would do the trick for you.  You don't even need to "return it" either since the init function itself doesn't return anything, so you could just call it.

Comment: bad idea leaving `this.init` there like that - what do you think `this` will be when that function is called?

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks! that's what copy/paste will get ya

Comment: It's still a bad idea to assign to `this.init` - it'll add `init` to `window`